# Generate a Hash from installed android application file in memory

Tags: android, hash

I am able to generate hash from a sample file (textFile.txt) which is created through my android application itself with the following code.
        Now I want to read the installed application file of my current android application(assuming it will be *.apk), read byte array from that file and produce the Hash value.

```
    Is it possible and how to do the same.Any help will be highly appreciated.


String FILENAME ="textFile.txt";
    String strMsgToSave = "content check";
    FileOutputStream fos;
    String outputTxt= "";
    String hash = null;
    String exception=null;
    try
    {
        fos = this.openFileOutput( FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        fos.write( strMsgToSave.getBytes() );
        fos.close();

        FileInputStream input = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
        byte [] buffer = new byte [65536];
        int l;
        while ((l = input.read (buffer)) > 0)
            output.write (buffer, 0, l);
        input.close ();
        output.close ();
        byte [] data = output.toByteArray ();
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-1" );
        byte[] bytes = data;
        digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        bytes = digest.digest();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for( byte b : bytes )
        {
            sb.append( String.format("%02X", b) );
        }
        hash = sb.toString();
        txtOutput.setText(hash);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: May I ask, why? If I'm not wrong, Google Play checks the sum to avoid problems.

Comment: @gian1200 : We want to implement validate our own process with respect to Security architecture. I have put comments on Substituit's answer. could you pls check the same and let me know if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the following code verified with two different android device and same application, found that the value that is retrieved is same irrespective to the devices. Following is the code for the same.So i guess I got my answer.

```
        File file=new File(getApplicationContext().getPackageCodePath());  
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
        byte [] buffer = new byte [65536];
        int l;
        while ((l = input.read (buffer)) > 0)
               output.write (buffer, 0, l);
        input.close ();
        output.close ();
        byte [] data = output.toByteArray ();
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-1" );
        byte[] bytes = data;
        digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        bytes = digest.digest();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for( byte b : bytes )
           sb.append( String.format("%02X", b) );
        hash = sb.toString();
```

**getApplicationContext().getPackageCodePath()** Return the full path to this context's primary Android package. The Android package is a ZIP file which contains application's primary code and assets. 
 Please let me know if this can be considered as a resolution to my problem or if any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could use `getApplicationContext.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir` to have the path to the apk file of your application and instantiate a new File with it.
It seems that you only need that to do what you want, your method should work.

Comment: Hi Substitue,
         I tried with the following to get the installed application file directory and files. I am able to get hash out of the same. But not sure whether the same is correct or not.
File file=new File(getApplicationContext().getPackageCodePath());
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();byte [] buffer = new byte [65536];int l;
while ((l = input.read (buffer)) > 0)
output.write (buffer, 0, l);
input.close ();output.close ();
byte [] data = output.toByteArray ();

Comment: MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-1" );
byte[] bytes = data;digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
bytes = digest.digest();StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( byte b : bytes )
{sb.append( String.format("%02X", b) );}
hash = sb.toString(); **getApplicationContext().getPackageCodePath()** Return the full path to this context's primary Android package. The Android package is a ZIP file which contains application's primary code and assets

Comment: I really don't know if there is a difference between those two methods. I'll test later and let you know. :)

Comment: Any more info on the same?